# Negative Celsius Temperature

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, units, si-units

If the Celsius scale is from 0 (freezing point) to a 100 (boiling point) then how is it that we can have negative numbers like -3 degrees Celsius? And can we also have temperatures like 120 degrees Celsius? Which is higher than the defined 100 degree Celsius.

But when it comes to kelvin we cannot have negatives because kelvin lowest temperature is defined as absolute 0

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you do not understand? What problem do you have with negative Celsius temperatures or temperatures over 100°C?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> If the Celsius scale is from 0 (freezing point) to a 100 (boiling point) then how is it that we can have negative numbers like -3 degrees Celsius?

The Celsius scale is a temperature scale where 0 is the freezing point and 100 is the boiling point of pure water at atmospheric pressure. There is absolutely no implication that the temperature scale is not valid outside of that range of temperatures.

Essentially, this can be considered the equation of a line, and as with any line it requires two distinct points to uniquely specify the line. However, the line itself is valid outside of the interval defined by those two points.

Answer (score 3):

The Celsius scale is defined from the freezing point and boiling point of water, yes.

But just because water freezes at $0\,^\circ\mathrm C$ doesn't mean that *all* substances freeze at this value. Household acetone, for example, freezes at $-94\,^\circ\mathrm C$. Sea water with its salt content freezes at $-2.4\,^\circ\mathrm C$.

This is how scales work in essence. You fix your scale to some known value that is easy to measure and verify, such as the properties of pure water. Then, you can characterize any other substance by this scale. The chosen fix-points - reference points - may be arbitrarily chosen, so there is no reason to believe that the zero value on this arbitrarily defined scale is the lowest of all possible values for any substance.

A scale that *is* fixed to the lowest of all possible temperature values - what we call **absolute zero** - has been invented and is called the Kelvin scale. There exist no real-life temperature values below $0\,\mathrm K$ because that value is *defined* to be the lowest possible value.